# Eclipse Gradle Tasks view no longer working

Tags: eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin, gradle-plugin

I used to be able to build with Gradle within Eclipse but now I just see the error icon overlaying the project name in the Gradle Tasks view and the message "No actions available" when I right click on it.  I can still build with gradle from the command line, so I know the issue has something to do with eclipse and not my gradle setup, but I can't find a solution.

I've tried updating buildship, updating eclipse, deleting the project and the .project file and then re-importing the project a a gradle project, running the gradle eclipse-related cleanup tasks, etc. Are there any other things I can try? has anyone else gotten this issue and fixed it?

[image]

Comment: Is your gradle build file free of syntax errors? What does the Problems View show?

Comment: There is one error:  "The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'my-project'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-project'.
Could not find method enabled() for arguments [true] on Report xml of type org.gradle.api.reporting.internal.TaskGeneratedSingleFileReport."

Comment: also, my gradle.build is absolutely free of syntax errors. It was all working fine until yesterday and I didn't change anything in it. And I can still build the project from the command line, just not in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the project from the eclipse workspace, deleted the .project and the .gradle folder, and then re-imported it as a gradle project. I specified to use a Specific Gradle version instead of using the Gradle wrapper when given the choice to choose the gradle distribution.  I think this was the issue.  The Gradle wrapper was using a version of gradle that was incompatible with my build.gradle.